# Can't find Node Module in Webpack Starter

Tags: angular

I´ve installed **Node 5.8.0** but get the following *error* when using **node start**. Any help for a ***newbie***?

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/lukashillebrand/Sites/angular2-webpack-starter/start'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:142:18)
at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: It would be better to add the screenshot of the error to the question directly. It would be even better to add the text instead of the screenshot because text in screenshots is not searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you run this?

```
npm install typings webpack-dev-server rimraf webpack -g

# install the repo with npm
npm install

# start the server
npm start
```

Comment: ok so if i don't run
        
        `npm install typings webpack-dev-server rimraf webpack -g`


i get that error